# Implementing a Read More link in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, reactjs

I am trying to implement a `Read More` link, which expands to show
more text after a click.  I am trying to do this the React way.

```
<!--html-->
<div class="initialText">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
  <a>
    Read More
  </a>
</div>

<div class="fullText">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

---

```
/* JavaScript */
/* @jsx DOM */
var component = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      expanded: false
    };
  },

  expandedText: function() {
    this.setState({
      expanded: true
    });       
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

I am new to React.  I am not sure how to handle everything inside the render method.  How can I implement this functionality in pure React?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So basically you want to display an extra div depending on the state property 'expanded'.

You can create a component conditionally. If you don't want a component you can just return null.
I would just have a small method like:

```
var component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
           expanded: false
       };
    },

    expandedText: function() {
        this.setState({
            expanded: true
        });       
    },

    getMoreTextDiv: function() {
        if (this.state.expanded) {
          return <div> My extended content </div>;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
    }
});
```

and your render function should become:

```
render: function() {
     var expandedDiv = this.getMoreTextDiv();
     return (
         <div>
             <a onClick={this.expandedText}>Read more</a>
             { expandedDiv }
         </div>
     );
}
```

Each time you call `setState()` you trigger `render()` using the new state.

If expanded is false you are going to return null as a component, which means basically, nothing. So nothing will be displayed.

When you click on your link it will update your state and the expanded value, so you will return a div as a component and it will be displayed.

I think a good start would be to read [this](http://jlongster.com/Removing-User-Interface-Complexity,-or-Why-React-is-Awesome).
This is a really great article and explains how render basically works, and the link with state.

You should also make sure you understand this kind of small example http://jsfiddle.net/3d1jzhh2/1/ to see how state and render are linked with each other.

Comment: Would it be best to place the `getMoreTextDiv()` method inside the render method or as part of the `React.createClass({  })`?

Comment: The method would be in createClass, but not in the render method. You could just have var expandedDiv = (this.state.expanded) ? <div>My content</div> : null; in render. I edited the answer.

Comment: Oh, yes.  I implemented it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer once again, but maybe someone will need it.

So basically you just need one component that will receieve the text you want to display.
Then you will use the ***useState*** hook that will set the value of text length - does it need to be short or long version displayed, and on the end one function that will toggle between short and long version of the text.

Code example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ReadMore = ({text}) => {
  const [isReadMore, setIsReadMore] = useState(true);
  const toggleReadMore = () => {setIsReadMore(!isReadMore)};

  return (
    <p className='testimonials__quote__text'>
      {isReadMore ? text.slice(0, 150): text }
      // condition that will render 'read more' only if the text.length is greated than 150 chars
      {text.length > 150 &&
        <span onClick={toggleReadMore}>
          {isReadMore ? '...read more' : ' ...show less'}
        </span>
      }
    </p>
  )
}

export default ReadMore;
```

Comment: if i have a list of long text, how do i make the state exclusively for each one of them? Your solutions works like charm on my project but when i press the '...read more' or '...read less' it affects all the other long texts in the list instead of just one

Comment: @Falady Well, can you share your code, just to see what's happening there, because it shouldn't have behavior like that.
Do you pass a list of texts to this component? If you do, then that's probably mistake, you should map over that list and for every item inside that list you should call this small component that will render your text in long and short state.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the read-more-react library, link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-more-react

```
npm install --save read-more-react
import ReadMoreReact from 'read-more-react';


<ReadMoreReact 
        text={yourTextHere}
        min={minimumLength}
        ideal={idealLength}
        max={maxLength} 
/>
```

Comment: Is adding a dependency on such a small library (38 stars as of today) for such a simple case really the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much on the right track. As stated in the react docs here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

it's just using a classic `if` and a variable, like this:

```
render: function() {
    var expandedContent;
    if (this.state.expanded) {
        expandedContent = <div>some details</div>;
    }

    return (
       <div>
           <div>Title or likewise</div>
           {expandedContent}
       </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have the same question however my content is in a 'p' or a 'div' tag. I want to show 'Read more' if the height of text is more than 300px. It's super easy in jquery but no idea how to do it in react?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm little late to answer this question but instead of using 2 strings why don't you do it by using just 1 string only.

check out this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-read-more
It'll solve the problem.

In case you are interested in code: https://github.com/oztek22/react-simple-read-more/blob/master/src/string-parser.jsx

Comment: Is adding a dependency on such a small library (0 stars as of today, 14 weekly downloads) for such a simple case really the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

That's the complete solution in React Js:

Call Component:

```js
<TeamCard description="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s." limit={150}/>
```

Component:

```js
const TeamCard = ({ description, limit }) => {
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false);
  return (
    <p className="text-center text-white text-base pt-3 font-normal pb-5">
      {description.length > limit ? (
        <div>
          {showAll ? (
            <div>
              {description}
              <br />
              <button
                onClick={() => setShowAll(false)}
                className="text-primary"
              >
                Read Less
              </button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              {description.substring(0, limit).concat("...")}
              <br />
              <button onClick={() => setShowAll(true)} className="text-primary">
                Read More
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        description
      )}
    </p>
  );
};
export default TeamCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

Built a simple component (stripped out the styles).

Usage:

```
<ReadMore text="this is a long text" maxChars={10} />
```

```js
const ReadMore = ({
      className,
      text,
      maxChars,
      readMoreText = "read more",
      readLessText = "read less",
    }) => {
      const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = React.useState(false);
      const hasReadMore = text.length > maxChars;

      return (
        <div className={className}>
          {text && (isExpanded || !hasReadMore) && (
            <p>
              {text}{" "}
              {hasReadMore && !!isExpanded && (
                <span
                  onClick={() => setIsExpanded(false)}
                >
                  <strong>{readLessText}</strong>
                </span>
              )}
            </p>
          )}
          {text && !isExpanded && !!hasReadMore && (
            <p>
              {text.slice(0, maxChars)}...{" "}
              <span
                onClick={() => setIsExpanded(true)}
              >
                <strong>{readMoreText}</strong>
              </span>
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
<div>
    <ReadMore text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." maxChars={200} />
<br/>
No "read more" link for texts of sufficient length.
<br/><br/>

<ReadMore text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book" maxChars={400} /></div>
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```