# Maximum amount of characters in a div/paragraph tag in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to add a "read more" link after my paragraph reaches 250 characters..got many solutions using javascript but i am unable to do it with reactjs. Help in any form will be great!
thanks
Example :
text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text...Read more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing a Read More link in React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996048/implementing-a-read-more-link-in-react-js)

Comment: No. This is not a duplicate  question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996048/implementing-a-read-more-link-in-react-js contains just expansion of text. I want the expansion of text post reaching a limit of 250 characters!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the difference from what you could see online is that you don't want to show a `Read more` button if the text has less than 250 characters.

It would be great if you could share what you already have, but just in case, here is a prototype:

```
class LongText extends Component { 
    state = { showAll: false }
    showMore = () => this.setState({showAll: true}); 
    showLess = () => this.setState({showAll: false});
    render() {
        const {content, limit} = this.props;
        const {showAll} = this.state;
        if(content.length<=limit) {
            // there is nothing more to show
            return <div>{content}<div>
        }
        if(showAll) {
            // We show the extended text and a link to reduce it
            return <div>
                {content}
                <a onClick={this.showLess}>Read less</a>
            </div>
        }
        // In the final case, we show a text with ellipsis and a `Read more` button
        const toShow = content.substring(0,limit)+"...";
        return <div>
            {toShow}
            <span onClick={this.showMore}>Read more</a>
        </div>
    }
}
```

**EDIT: with hooks**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const LongText = ({ content,limit}) => {
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false);

  const showMore = () => setShowAll(true);
  const showLess = () => setShowAll(false);

  if (content.length <= limit) {
    // there is nothing more to show
    return <div>{content}</div>
  }
  if (showAll) {
    // We show the extended text and a link to reduce it
    return <div> 
      {content} 
      <button onClick={showLess}>Read less</button> 
    </div>
  }
  // In the final case, we show a text with ellipsis and a `Read more` button
  const toShow = content.substring(0, limit) + "...";
  return <div> 
    {toShow} 
    <button onClick={showMore}>Read more</button>
  </div>
}


const App = () => <div>
  <LongText content = "Short text" limit = {10}/> 
  <LongText content = "Very long text, very very long" limit = {10} /> 
</div>


ReactDOM.render( <App/>,document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
button {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Was getting stuck with this! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 10):

A simpler and more expressive example than the others posted, using ES6:

```
// Outside component
const MAX_LENGTH = 250;

render() {
  const { text } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
      {text.length > MAX_LENGTH ?
        (
          <div>
            {`${text.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH)}...`}<a href="#">Read more</a>
          </div>
        ) :
        <p>{text}</p>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61056/) demonstrating this.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the answer from [Implementing a Read More link in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996048/implementing-a-read-more-link-in-react-js) and load the reduced text with the `substr()` method like this:

```
var component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
       return {
          expanded: false,
          myText: 'bla bla bla'
       };
    },

    expandedText: function() {
        this.setState({
          expanded: true
        });       
    },

    getMoreTextDiv = function() {
        if (this.state.expanded) {
          return myText;
        } else {
          return myText.substr(0, 250);
        }
    }

    render: function() {
        var expandedDiv = this.getMoreTextDiv();
        return (
           <div>
               <a onClick={ this.expandedText }>Read more</a>
               { expandedDiv }
           </div>
        );
    }
});
```