# react slidetoggle with this

Tags: jquery, reactjs, this, slidetoggle

I'm trying to get slideToggle to work with React like I did with jQuery, but I'm unable to figure out how to do it. 
I have a list of different recipes, and not to make the page incredibly long, I want to hide the content and only show the heading of each recipe. When the user clicks the heading, it will show the content for that particular recipe. If the heading is clicked again, it will hide that particular content. 
I want to use same className ('content') for each recipe content, so I would need "this" to determine which content I want to show. How can I do this in React?

In jQuery I got it work like this

```
 $("h2").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('slow');   
});
```

but after several tests in React the best I got was hiding the last content with the example from this page ([React jQuery slideToggle](https://codepen.io/souporserious/pen/vGRPmo))

I wasn't able to get this one work, probably the way to get this working..?
[react using jquery to slideToggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979921/react-using-jquery-to-slidetoggle)
I think this is bit out of date and could be done better nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here will work well:

[Implementing a Read More link in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996048/implementing-a-read-more-link-in-react-js)

Alternatively, you could expand the text using [React Router Page Transition](https://github.com/trungdq88/react-router-page-transition)

[Demo](https://trungdq88.github.io/react-router-page-transition/simple/)